# What is the best way to concatenate two float64 columns without converting to str in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm still a Python beginner and the project I'm working on right now requires me to concatenate 2 float columns to datetime.

The data looks something like this

```
Date = [20191219, 20190812]    

Time = [31547, 121652]
```

What's the best way to convert this to datetime format?

I tried to join both cols using `dat['Date'].map(str) +''+ dat['Time'].map(str)` but the values return with .0 added at the end... i.e 20191219.0, 31547.0 so datetime does not recognize this format.

Comment: I tried above code but I am getting those additional `.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both columns separately to datetimes and then sum together with subtract helper `date`s created after converting times to datetimes:

```
Date = [20191219.0, 20190812]
Time = [31547, 121652.0]
dat = pd.DataFrame({'Date':Date,'Time':Time})

d = pd.to_datetime(dat['Date'], format='%Y%m%d') 
t = pd.to_datetime(dat['Time'], format='%H%M%S')
dat['date'] = d + (t - t.dt.floor('d'))
print (dat)
         Date      Time                date
0  20191219.0   31547.0 2019-12-19 03:15:47
1  20190812.0  121652.0 2019-08-12 12:16:52
```

Another solution is replace possible `.0` to empty strings:

```
s = (dat['Date'].astype(str).str.replace('\.0', '') + ' ' +  
     dat['Time'].astype(str).str.replace('\.0', ''))
dat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
```

Comment: done! I was wondering if there was an efficient way to convert this timestamp to EST?.... Please advise; thanks!